# What's the dual space of $c_{0}^{\mathcal {A}}(X)$?

Tags: banach-spaces

Suppose that $X$ is a Banach space and $({\mathcal {A}},\alpha)$ is a Banach operator ideal. A sequence $(x_{n})_{n=1}^{\infty}$ in $X$ is said to be ${\mathcal {A}}-$convergent to zero if there exist an operator $T\in {\mathcal {A}}(Z,X)$ for some Banach space $Z$ and a sequence $(z_{n})_{n=1}^{\infty}$ in $Z$ that converges to zero in norm such that $x_{n}=Tz_{n}(n=1,2,...)$. We denote all such sequences in $X$ by $c_{0}^{\mathcal {A}}(X)$. Then $c_{0}^{\mathcal {A}}(X)$ is a normed space under the sup norm, but is not complete(observed by J. Alejandro Chavez-Dominguez)unless $c_{0}^{\mathcal {A}}(X)$ coincides with $c_{0}(X)$. J. Alejandro Chavez-Dominguez defined a new norm on $c_{0}^{\mathcal {A}}(X)$ by: $$\parallel (x_{n})_{n=1}^{\infty}\parallel_{c_{0}^{\mathcal {A}}(X)}=\inf \{\alpha(T)\cdot\parallel (z_{n})_{n=1}^{\infty}\parallel_{c_{0}(Z)}\}.$$ where the infimum is taken over all representations of the sequence $(x_{n})_{n=1}^{\infty}$. Alejandro also proved that $c_{0}^{\mathcal {A}}(X)$ is a Banach space under this new norm. Our natural questions are the followings:

$\bullet$ What's the dual space of $c_{0}^{\mathcal {A}}(X)$ with the sup norm?

$\bullet$ What's the dual space of $c_{0}^{\mathcal {A}}(X)$ with $\parallel \cdot\parallel_{c_{0}^{\mathcal {A}}(X)}$?

Comment: Obviously $c_0^{\mathcal A}(X)$ is a dense subspace of $c_0(X)$ (sup norm) and hence the spaces have the same dual, which is $\ell_1(X^*)$.

Comment: @Alejandro: Since $\parallel \cdot\parallel_{\infty}\leq \parallel \cdot \parallel_{c^{\mathcal {A}}_{0}(X)}$, the dual space of $(c^{\mathcal {A}}_{0}(X),\parallel \cdot\parallel_{c^{\mathcal {A}}_{0}(X)})$ contains the dual of $(c^{\mathcal {A}}_{0}(X),\parallel\cdot \parallel_{\infty})$,which is $l_{1}(X^{*})$.